# How are global variables accessed in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, mips

I've seen global variables accessed directly by name, such as in the following video:

https://youtu.be/zs-TKZNGdsk?list=PL5b07qlmA3P6zUdDf-o97ddfpvPFuNa5A&t=614

**EG:**

```
        .data
sum:    .word 0
        .text
        .globl  main

main:
        sw $a0, sum
```

This doesn't compile for me on MARS 4.2, I get the following error:

```
line 13 column 9: "sw": Too few or incorrectly formatted operands. Expected: sw $t1,-100($t2
```

I have also seen sum($gp) used, on the following site:
https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse378/02sp/sections/section3-2.html

So I have written

```
        .data
sum:    .word 0
        .text
        .globl  main

main:
        lw $a0, sum($gp)
```

Which also fails to compile, with this error:

```
line 11 column 17: "sum": operand is of incorrect type
```

---

**Background info:**
I'm writing a compiler.  I know I can access the global variables through a literal offset of $gp, but I'm trying to avoid the enumeration and lookup process that that would require.  Please tell me I can access them by name and that I'm just using some wonky version of MARS.

Comment: `sum` is an address, i.e. a 32 bit quantity. It is too big to fit in a 16 bit register offset.

Comment: assembly language is defined by the assembler the program that does the assembling.  so this isnt a MIPS thing necessarily it is how does assembler X (which happens to target mips) do such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

I updated from MARS 4.2 (which my school forced us to use last semester) to MARS 4.5 and this solved my problem.